# App screen won't rotate both sides on landscape mode

Tags: android, eclipse, landscape, screen-rotation

I'm writing an application for android that runs on landscape mode.
When i'm rotating my device on 180 degrees it stays the way it is.
What can i do\change and where so it can run on both horizontal directions?

Comment: try using `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` or `android:screenOrientation="sensor"` with your activity

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Manifest add below code in activity you want to have both sides.

```
 android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

Comment: Rawat Ji Dhanyawad.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices just don't do the "upside down" mode. My Galaxy Nexus rotates only to three orientations.

Comment: Hey Christine! My device is LG G3 and i know for sure that it can run 4 orientations, but thank you anyway

Comment: The screenorientation parameter works on my Galaxy Nexus too. Never noticed that before :-)
On most devices, afaik, you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device is auto rotation is ON or working fine than

use this code in your manifest.xml in your activity in which you waana rotate d screen.

**android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"**

it works fine for me :)